# Python Sphinx exclude patterns

Tags: python, python-sphinx, exclusionpath

I'm generating documentation with Sphinx for project with structure like this :

```
+ project
|
+- docs
|
+- tests
|
+- workflow -+- definitions -+- <some folders>
             | 
             +- <rest of the project>
```

I want to exclude tests, and workflow/definition from documentation.

I tried exclude pattern in docs/conf.py

```
exclude_patterns = ['**/workflow/definitions', 'workflow/definitions', '*workflow/definitions', 'workflow/definitions*', 'workflow/definitions/*', 'workflow/definitions/*.*']
```

But even though workflow/definitions are still automatically generated.

Could someone show me correct exclude pattern how to ignore 'definitions' folder ?

Comment: `exclude_patterns` can be used to exclude RST files only (when running sphinx-build). Does the workflow/definitions directory contain Python files or RST files?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

[`exclude_patterns`](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/config.html#confval-exclude_patterns) can be used to exclude source files (reStructuredText  files) from processing by **sphinx-build**.

`exclude_patterns` has no effect when using [**sphinx-apidoc**](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/man/sphinx-apidoc.html) to generate reStructuredText  files from Python modules (but you can tell **sphinx-apidoc** that certain pathnames should be excluded from the generation).

Comment: `but you can tell sphinx-apidoc that certain pathnames should be excluded from the generation` How do you do that? I can't find anything in neither the the [apidoc pages](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/man/sphinx-apidoc.html) nor the [autodoc config docs](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/usage/extensions/autodoc.html#module-sphinx.ext.autodoc).

Comment: See `EXCLUDE_PATTERN` at http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/man/sphinx-apidoc.html

Comment: For anyone else who ran into a similar issue as I, `EXCLUDE_PATTERN` also needs to include module path.  e.g `sphinx-apidoc -f -o source .. *setup*` still generated setup.rst from setup.py, but `sphinx-apidoc -f -o source .. ../*setup*` worked as expected.

Answer (score 2):

See EXCLUDE_PATTERN in `sphinx-apidoc --help`

```
usage: sphinx-apidoc [OPTIONS] -o <OUTPUT_PATH> <MODULE_PATH> [EXCLUDE_PATTERN, ...]

The <EXCLUDE_PATTERN>s can be file and/or directory patterns that will be excluded from generation.
```

Answer (score 1):

Docs for [exclude_patterns](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/config.html#confval-exclude_patterns) indicate that `'workflow/definitions'` should ignore that directory, assuming that the source files all end with `.rst`.

You can [configure the source file suffices as a list](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/config.html#confval-source_suffix):

```
source_suffix = ['.rst', '.txt']
```